# SQL Server temporal table for historical changes only

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I have a table of data that changes frequently. I don’t care about changes to data that is less than 30 days old. No need to track those versions. But once the data is about 30 days old I want to track changes to it. Is this possible using a single temporal table? Or would I need to have my ‘real time’ table with everything in it and a separate ‘archive table’ that we would ETL in only the 30 day old data and turn the temporal on that on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or would I need to have my ‘real time’ table with everything in it and
> a separate ‘archive table’ that we would ETL in only the 30 day old
> data/datetime and turn the temporal on that on?

You have to use this approach since when you configure temporal tables, you cannot setup an **30 days offset** on some date attribute.

Therefore, as you pointed in the initial question, the logical workaround is to create a scheduled process which MERGE changes into the archival table that has enabled TEMPORAL TABLE functionality, so it will maintain a history of changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible using a single temporal table? Or would I need to
> have my ‘real time’ table with everything in it and a separate
> ‘archive table’ that we would ETL in only the 30 day old data and turn
> the temporal on that on?

When a System Versioned temporal table is created it automatically creates a history table which is suffixed with '_history'.  While system versioning is on there is no way to delete from the _history.  The simple answer is to switch the versioning off, delete the rows from _history table, then switch system versioning back on.  Like [this](https://bertwagner.com/2017/07/04/how-to-automatically-purge-historical-data-from-a-temporal-table/).  There are lots of articles and examples on SO and other sites.